# Better sentence structure - Inversion sentence with should

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion, should

My original sentence is:

Should the doctrine of democracy be proved to be an important and effective mean to control the government, it should not be reformed insofar as the effect of which is to limit the effectiveness of it

I am not sure if the sentence is grammatically correct.

Do you think "should" is a better choice than "if" in this sentence?

Having considered some of the comments below, would it be better if I put it as -

Should the doctrine be proved to be an effective control against the government, any reform that might undermine its effectiveness would be undesirable

Thank you so much

Comment: The first part of the sentence is fine (except *means* should be plural). The part that needs correcting is *"... it should not be reformed insofar as the effect of which is to limit ..."*

Comment: There are many things wrong with this sentence, but the usage of  "should" is not wrong.  The overuse of "effective" and "effect", and the probable misuse of  "insofar",  are what you should be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. May I ask what is wrong with my usage of "insofar as"? How should I correct it?

Comment: No major syntactic errors, but it's a bit of a brain twister -- it rambles on too long and combines too many different conditional thoughts.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Think for bringing that out. May I also know if there is any minor syntactic mistake, even if there isn't major error?

Comment: Starting with "insofar" it's a bit hard to parse, largely because the antecedents of the pronouns are unclear.  Whether the syntax is technically correct or not is irrelevant, since the sentence must be rewritten.  At a minimum, "insofar as the effect of such reform would limit the effectiveness of the doctrine."  (Though, as I said, it's unclear what "it" refers to, so "doctrine" may be the wrong word.)  But probably a more complete rewrite is in order.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the repetition of "should" and to make the sentence feel less heavy, I'd go for:

***Should*** the doctrine of democracy **be proved** to be an important and effective mean to control the government, **reforming it were/is to be avoided**, **as this might limit its effectiveness.**

or:

***If*** the doctrine of democracy **were proved** to be an important and effective mean to control the government, it should not be reformed, **as this might limit its effectiveness.**

or:

***If*** the doctrine of democracy **proved itself** to be an important and effective mean to control the government, it should not be reformed, **as this might limit its effectiveness.**

or:

***To the extent that*** the doctrine of democracy **were proved** to be an important and effective mean to control the government, it should not be reformed, **as this might limit its effectiveness.**

This particular inversion was used in the 19C:

***Were*** the doctrine of democracy **proved** **to be** an important and effective mean to control the government, it should not be reformed, **as this might limit the effectiveness of it.**

but isn't too common these days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me that there are some subtle differences between your first two suggestions and my sentence, as I implicitly avoid to suggest an outright refusal to such a reform. To contextualise my question - As democracy embodies a complex structure, some degree of reform may be supported, but other parts of this doctrine should not be reformed if it were proved to be an important mean.

Do you think I somehow misapprehended your suggestions? I apologise for troubling you with this as I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: Your text here is a bit different. I'll leave that to others.